# rollover on touch device

Tags: touch, device, mouseover, rollover

My team is developing a HTML5 web application with Edge and JavaScript. We need to support touch devices also, but we've bumped into a problem:

How can we simulate a rollover or mouse-over event on a touch device?

Any idea is welcome, not necessarily a code example.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ergonomic problem, not a technical one.

And the short answer is : you cant :)

Put simply, all the rollover actions on a standard device must be rethink with click actions.
For exemple, a rollover top navigation menu on a touch screen device must work with clicks on the menu instead of roll over actions.

At least this is what we do for multi-support web applications...